# How to create retrofit POST MultiPart Request Android Kotlin? Http 400 Bad Request

Tags: android, image, file, retrofit, multipart

I've followed multiple tutorials and guides about this subject and all of them seem to differ in terms of which way is best to achieve the result.
Basically I want to send a request with the following body:
[Postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDSpo.png)

And the following Authorization Header (Bearer Token):
[Postman Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WA7H.png)

For that, I have an ImageView from which I get my bitmap and then my file to upload.
This is My API Interface

```
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
@POST("v1/images/variations")
@Multipart
suspend fun requestVariation(@Header("Authorization") token: String,
                             @Part("n") n: RequestBody,
                             @Part("size") size: RequestBody,
                             @Part image: MultipartBody.Part) :Call<ResponseClass>
```

I've tried different approaches, like setting "n" and "size" to Int and String respectively.
Same result.

This is my Service Builder

```
object VariationBuilder {

    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.openai.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()

    fun<T> buildService (service :Class<T>): T{
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
}
```

And this is my call to the requestVariation function inside my Main Activity.
Here I get "n" from a Spinner, The Bearer token from an EditText and view is an ImageView, a parameter to the function. Size is straight up hard-coded for now.

```
val linearLayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.img_linear_layout)
val numberSpinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
val tokenText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.token_box)

linearLayout.removeAllViews()
val newID = 1
view.id = newID
linearLayout.addView(view)

val cantSelec = numberSpinner.selectedItem.toString().toInt() - 1

val retrofit = VariationBuilder.buildService(RestApiInterface::class.java)

val dir = File(externalCacheDir,File.separator + "Variations")
dir.mkdirs()

val fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis())
val file: File = File(dir,File.separator + fileName)
file.createNewFile()

//Convert bitmap to byte array
val bitmap: Bitmap? = createBitmapFromView(this@MainActivity,view)
val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos) // YOU can also save it in JPEG
val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()

//write the bytes in file
val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
fos.write(bitmapdata)
fos.flush()
fos.close()

Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Espere, cargando...",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

retrofit.requestVariation(
    "Bearer " + tokenText.text.toString(),
    RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,cantSelec.toString()),
    RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,"512x512"),
    image = MultipartBody.Part
        .createFormData(
            "image",
            fileName,
            RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, file)
        )
)
```

Obviously I'm missing somethig but I can't figure out what the problem is.
Can someone help?

I just tried changing the API definition for the body and the parameters to the call, as I have made several other retrofit successful requests, but all of them with a simple json Body and a Bearer Token Authorization Header.

Comment: Make sure that the request accepts "image" as field name. `image = MultipartBody.Part
        .createFormData(
            "image",
            fileName,
            RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, file)
        )`

Comment: Yes, when using Postman I use the name image and it works properly.